# Why does this @synthesize implementation return an error in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, synthesize

```
#import "CLSViewController.h"

@implementation CLSViewController

@synthesize statusText = _statusText;

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setStatusText:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *title = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
->  statusText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ button pressed.", title];
}

@end
```

The line that says statusText.text = ...

Did I not synthesize it correctly? Removing the `= _statusText;` from it gets rid of the error, but I thought we were supposed to set it to something.

Comment: Others have described the difference between the instance variable and the property. In terms of when you should use which, see [Use Accessor Methods to Set Property Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW5) and [Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to access the property, you should use

```
self.statusText.text = ....
```

you can also access the variable directly using _statusText:

```
_statusText.text = ....
```

If you remove _statusText from the synthesize line, the instance variable name will be assumed to be "statusText", so that is why your situation works when you remove it.

```
@synthesize statusText
....
statusText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ button pressed.", title]; // this works
```

IMO you should always access it as a property (e.g. self.statusText) except in init/dealloc since you are declaring it as such.

Comment: However, having a variable named statusText is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

the code:

```
@synthesize statusText = _statusText;
```

means statusText is a public field of your class, _statusText is a private symbol.
Because so you have to modify your code like this:

```
self.statusText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ button pressed.", title];
```

or this:

```
_statusText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ button pressed.", title];
```